# How do I install pytelegrambotapi on visual code studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, telegram, telebot

I am quite confuse as I tried to install it using the command $ pip install pyTelegramBotAPI on VS terminal but it does not seem to work https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYXMA.png (image of the error), I tried looking up for telegrambot extension but could not any in VS. Please guide me through. Thank you ~ I really want to import telebot but it does not work till I install it ( i assume)

Comment: the problem is the `$`, not `pyTelegramBotAPI`, where does the `$` originates

Comment: Hi, about the $, i just copy that whole command from the internet. Even without the $, I still won't be able to install it. So i do not know how to install

Comment: the `$` is meant to indicate the CLI prompt and should not be copied. What is the error you get without the `$`

Comment: Program 'pip.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: Here's the error they gave ~

Comment: @bryan Can the error report be completely added to the article?

Comment: What article? I do not understand what do you mean. Sorry

Comment: @bryan As the picture shows, I can't reproduce the problem you encounter. Can you update your error code in the form of a picture? Or restart a new issue. 
 https://imgur.com/a/IJQkhSi

Comment: imgur.com/VDvgW56, Hello, here the picture.  @MingJie-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, in **Command Prompt** (Admin) try to run pip install using the Python executable:

```
python -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/m4qZ4jY, does that mean i have installed it successfully? Also if it was successful, does that mean i have also install it in visual code?

Comment: @bryan yes. And if you choose the correct interpreter in vscode, the packgae can be recognized as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong information or copied the wrong symbol here.
"$" it means linux bash. Don't copy that.
Do you use windows:
press Win key. type **cmd** Enter type ***pip install pytelegrambotapi** hi Enter
Everything will be OK.
If linux.
User virtualenv
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv
python3 -m venv 
source \bin\activate
pip install pytelegrambotapi
OKKK. have fun. linux have some problems with pytelegrambotapi so just use virtualenv. To deactivate type **deactivate** or **source \bin\deactivate**.
Later...